# php curl returns empty string when trying to search keywords

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to scrape this url: "https://www.petfinder.com/animal-shelters-and-rescues/search/?location=&shelter_name=DREAM animal rescue" to search for keyword "DREAM animal rescue" with php curl, but it's returning an empty string.

i tried using file_get_contents() none is working, my code is below;

```
session_start();
include("includes/db_conn.php");
include ('simple_html_dom.php');    
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.petfinder.com/animal-shelters-and-rescues/search/?location=&shelter_name=DREAM animal rescue");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === FALSE) {
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($curl);
    $error=1;
  } else {
    //   var_dump($response);
    //   echo $response;
    $error=0;
}
curl_close($curl);


if ($error ==0){
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html -> load($response);

    // echo($response);

    var_dump($response);

}
```

I hope to get the search results and parse it, please anyone, i need help fast

Comment: Is it correct `=DREAM animal rescue`in your url. Shouldn't it be `=DREAM+animal+rescue`

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer toolbar the initial URL is redirected to
https://www.petfinder.com/v2/search/organizations?latitude=13.46256&longitude=144.69282&name_substring=DREAM&page=1
Try:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.petfinder.com/v2/search/organizations?latitude=13.46256&longitude=144.69282&name_substring=DREAM&page=1",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err)
{
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
else
{
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but i'm still not getting the search results from it, i'm kind of a webscrapping newbie. i'd appreciate any help pls